# What is the profession called of someone who color grades films?

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request

How can I say the profession of one who color grades films, in German? In English this is said as "colo(u)rist" or "colo(u)r corrector".

This is a niche profession, however many of my family members work in this industry, so it comes up for me in conversations.

What I tried:

- I looked up colorist / colourist on [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/colorist). Doesn't provide the definition I am looking for and has no translations.
- I looked for the article on English wikipedia.  There is an article for [Colorist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorist) which has a [German version](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorist), but it's a different kind of colorist, and there's an English article for [Color grading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_grading) with no German version linked.  This suggests "Colorist(in)" as a possible translation
- I checked on [dict.leo.org](https://dict.leo.org), which gives [Kolorist(in)](https://dict.leo.org/german-english/Kolorist) as a translation, but doesn't say for which definition. (This is the dictionary my course instructor has recommended)
- I checked [Kolorist(in)](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Kolorist) on dwds which does not include the definition I am looking for. Colorist(in) redirects to Kolorist(in).

Comment: Why do you think the German Wikipedia article is about a different kind of colorist? Citation of the first sentence: "Ein Colorist ist ein Fachmann der Bildenden Kunst, der bei Comics, Filmen und anderen Medien Farben (lat.-engl. colors) hinzufügt oder abstimmt." (A colorist is a specialist/professional of visual arts who adds or adjusts/tunes colors in comics, films and other media.)

Comment: @Bodo Ah! I didn't read the German article.  I meant that the *English* article was about a different kind of colorist, and it is.  I guess I should have checked the German article had the same subject, instead of assuming it was the same since they were linked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filmlichtbestimmer

> Der Filmlichtbestimmer, kurz auch Lichtbestimmer, ist ein Spezialist,
> der einzelne Filmszenen je nach gewünschter Stimmung auf Helligkeit,
> Farbe und Kontrast abstimmt. Das Berufsbild wurde, beginnend in etwa
> ab dem Jahr 2000, weitgehend durch den Coloristen abgelöst, der
> mittels Digital Intermediate und nicht mehr mit Chemie und Mechanik
> arbeitet.

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farbkorrektur#Additive_Farbkorrektur

> Der Beruf des Farbkorrekteurs in der Filmbranche wird als
> Lichtbestimmer, im digitalen Bereich als Colorist bezeichnet.

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farbkorrektur#Farbkorrektur_bei_Film_und_Video

> Heutzutage verwendet man für den Vorgang der Farbkorrektur meist den
> englischen Begriff Color Grading oder kurz Grading. Daraus leiten sich
> die alternativen Berufsbezeichnungen Colour Grader und Color-Timer ab.

- The old profession is: **Filmlichtbestimmer**
- The digital version is: **Colorist**
- **Colour Grader** und **Color-Timer** is also used